# Facebook php sdk post to user wall show user to user

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I using Facebook php sdk to post to users wall

```
$userId = $_POST["chckuser"][$i];
$facebook->api('/'.$userId.'/feed', 'post', array('message' => 'Hi'));
```

and i using this permissions :

```
$loginUrl =$facebook>getLoginUrl(array('redirect_uri'=>$homeurl,'scope'=>'publish_stream,user_groups,manage_pages'));
```

But appears in the user's wall "User to user"

The problem appears in this image

http://i.imm.io/TA9F.jpeg

What is the problem please and thank u

Comment: Sorry but what are you trying to achieve if not posting to another user's wall from a logged in user?

Comment: Not a question really! If you are using `feed` to post on other user's wall , then obviously `User to user` will appear!

Answer (score 0):

From the image I can see that the current user and the user with id `$userId` are different users. If you want to post to current user's wall (and you sound like you want to do it like that) you don't have to check  you can simple use `me/feed`:

```
$facebook->api('/me/feed', 'post', array('message' => 'Hi'));
```

This will post to the wall of user that is authed and is currently using your app.

Answer (score 0):

```
$userId = $_POST["chckuser"][$i];
```

This is your problem. You are posting to somebody else's wall. If you post to somebody else's wall, you will get the user to user message. It isn't a bug, its a very sensible feature.

As Konrad said above, just post to /me/feed instead.